# A better way to do aes_encrypt and how to store keyString for aes_encrypt

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently do encryption like this in my php script:

```
select name from table;

while (php loop) {
   echo encrypt();
   echo $name;
}
```

This is my encrypt function.

```
function encrypt($thisVal)
{
   select lower(hex(aes_encrypt(:what,:salt))) as encValue
}
```

Is there a way I can do the encrypt part without using the function I'm using, or using encrypt in the sql itself? I dont want to put the `aes_encrypt` part in the sql itself since, if things went wrong people could see what's being done. Can I get `name` encrypted somehow and returned with the sql's results. Maybe keep it in a MySql function.

Also, what is the safest way to store the keyString that's used in `aes_encrypt`. I currently store them as constants in a php file.

Comment: For what purpose are you storing passwords? Is it just for user authentication and you never really *need* the plaintext passwords, or do you actually need the plaintext passwords again? If the former, you don't want *encryption*, you want a completely different **hashing** algorithm to begin with.

Comment: Not the user password. I meant the keystring that's used in `aes_encrypt`

Comment: OK, misunderstanding there. Still, it helps to explain the scenario, for what purpose you're encrypting what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can do the encrypt part without using the function I'm using

What makes you think doing the encryption in PHP is a bad idea or insecure? Generally speaking it's safe to do your encryption via PHP (for example with [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.mcrypt.php)).

> Also, what is the safest way to store the keyString that's used in aes_encrypt. I currently store them as constants in a php file.

For best security, store the encryption key outside of the public HTML (or out of the document root). A constants file is OK as long as it doesn't reside in the document root. Also consider which users on the server have access to the file - you want it to be a "need to know" basis.